# Find a method to calculate the lowest possible number of moves from x to y using recursion

Tags: java, recursion

I need to write a method which calculates the lowest possible moves from x to y with these actions:

1. add 1
2. multiply by 2

I'v tried to check if y is odd then enter the recursion with y-1
and if y is even enter the recursion with y/2

```
public static int minOps(int x, int y)
    {
        if(x==y)
            return 0;
        if(x>y)
            return 0;
        if(y%2==1)
            return 1+minOps(x,y-1);
        if(y%2==0)
            return 1+minOps(x,y/2);

        return 0;
    }
```

For example, if x= 10 and y=24 then the output will be 3.
Because (10+1+1)*2=24 and that is the lowest possible moves and not 10*2+1+1+1+1

Comment: I think you are missing the point of the exercise. You should always test both methods, then compare their results, then return the minimum of the two.

Comment: Other people who solved that problem said thet thay did it with backtracking

Comment: @PatrickParker you don't need to always check the /2 case: it's not feasible of `y` is odd. But sure, if even, try both (assuming dividing by 2 doesn't make your number too small!).

Comment: Do you know how to fix the code that I did?